# parsing arabic text with json issue

Tags: objective-c, json, xcode

i am new to JSON and Objective-c language by Apple. i was just trying to do some practice and stuff

with yandex.ru translate api

i tried this URL

> https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate?key=trnsl.1.1.20170517T154730Z.927d87b76de60242.7a92e4612778a4838d40ab192df5297d2a1af4ed&text=Hello&lang=ar

which is translating (HELLO) from english to arabic.. still fine

on my project in Xcode i tried this code
to make things work

```
 NSString *jsonString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate?key=trnsl.1.1.20170517T154730Z.927d87b76de60242.7a92e4612778a4838d40ab192df5297d2a1af4ed&text=Hello&lang=ar"];
jsonString = [jsonString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:jsonString];
NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSError *error=nil;
//NSLog(@"%@",dictionary);

NSArray* dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                             options:kNilOptions
                                               error:&error];


NSLog(@"Your JSON Object: %@ Or Error is: %@", [dictionary valueForKey:@"text"], error);
NSString*string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dictionary valueForKey:@"text"]];
```

until here its fine.. but it returns a wrong value on the Log 
instead of (مرحبا) its

> Your JSON Object: (
>       "\U0645\U0631\U062d\U0628\U0627"
>   )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value is correct. It's the object – an array – in conjunction with `NSLog` which produces this output displaying Unicode tokens.

First of all the JSON object is a dictionary rather than an array, the Objective-C compiler is so polite not to complain at this moment.

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data ...
```

Secondly never use `valueForKey` to get a single object from a dictionary, use key subscription

```
NSLog(@"Your JSON Object: %@ Or Error is: %@", dictionary[@"text"], error);
```

However the value for key `text` is an array. To get the result string get the first item in the array and you should check if there is no error and if the array is not empty to avoid a out-of-range crash.

```
if (error == nil) {
    NSArray *result = dictionary[@"text"];
    if (result.count > 0) {
        NSString *string = result[0];
    }
}
```

Now when you assign the `string` to a label or text view you will get the expected `مرحبا`.

---

PS: Two other improvements of your code:

- You don't need `stringWithFormat` if there are no format arguments

  ```
  NSString *jsonString = @"https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate?key=trnsl.1.1.20170517T154730Z.927d87b76de60242.7a92e4612778a4838d40ab192df5297d2a1af4ed&text=Hello&lang=ar";
  ```
- To escape invalid characters use `NSURLComponents` which is able to do that in a smart way:

  ```
  NSURLComponents *components = [NSURLComponents componentsWithString:jsonString];
  NSURL *url = components.URL;
  ```